# Server Object Model to recursively loop through All Sites Collections and there sub-sites of Web-application

Tags: ssom

This is my First Post on SharePoint and I am new to SharePoint.I am listening lot of positive buzz on sharepoint.stackexchange , And i hope I too get the same support from you all folks.

My requirement for one of my Web-application(Sales Department) is to get all the **Site collections and there sub-sites(including children and their children and so on)** , Through Server-object Model and bind to grid.

I see lot of Power-Shell Scripts, But due to my infant stage to SharePoint I couldn't able to understand , Also my requirement is to achieve this using Server Object Model

Can any one help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

For iterate through **All Sites Collections** and **their sub-sites recursively** using **SSOM** so use this code below :

```
string siteurl = "Your Web Application URL";

SPSite tmpRoot = new SPSite(siteurl);
SPSiteCollection tmpRootColl = tmpRoot.WebApplication.Sites;

//Enumerate through each site collection
foreach (SPSite tmpSite in tmpRootColl)
{
   //Enumerate through each sub-site
    foreach (SPWeb tmpWeb in tmpSite.AllWebs)
    {
        //Gets a Boolean value for checking if sub-site inheriting permissions or not. 
        if(tmpWeb.HasUniqueRoleDefinitions)
         {
          //Do something
         }
        tmpWeb.Dispose();
     }  
 tmpSite.Dispose();           
 }
```

Comment: Remember to dispose the `SPWeb` and `SPSite` objects (e.g. `tmpWeb.Dispose()`, `tmpSite.Dispose()`) at the end of each loop.

Comment: Diceler  | Youssef 

Thanks for your response , How can I loop to the sites holding unique permissions( broken Inheritance)

Comment: @AxLearner check the updated Answer above.